# Custom forms Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-form, list-form

Is it possible to create custom form like this in picture, and how? I'm using Sharepoint 2013 standard. [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can check this: http://summit7systems.com/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use SharePoint Designer 2013. Create a New form for your list and write your html in the `xslt` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Sharepoint Designer 2013 for it. This tutorial gives you a step by step description on how to create Custom Forms:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx